# Thymeleaf stopped resolving layout templates after migrating to Thymeleaf 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a simple Spring Boot application in version 1.5.7 and I am trying to migrate it to version 2.0.0. I am almost done but there is one last piece missing and that is Thymeleaf.

Everything was working fine in the old version but after the migration, Spring Boot stopped resolving any templates (both pages and emails).

I have all templates `src/main/resources/templates`. Additionaly, I have layout called default in `src/main/resources/templates/layout` which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head th:replace="fragments/header :: head"></head>
<body>

    <div id="page">
        <nav class="navigation" th:replace="fragments/navigation"></nav>

        <div class="container">
            <div layout:fragment="container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My pages link to this layout like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorate="layout/default">

<body>

    <div layout:fragment="container">
...
</body>
</html>
```

The navigation fragment in localted in `src/main/resources/templeats/fragments`

In Spring Boot 2, the login page is rendered but the layout is not applied (so the navigation bar and styles are missing). Did something change in version 2.0.0? I have not found any solution to this in officials docs or migration guide.

EDIT: As suggested in the answer, it is caused by migrating to Thymeleaf 3. I updated my question with some changes reflecting the migration guide but the code is still not injecting the layout.

I have tried `layout:data-layout-decorate=~{layout/default}` and layout:data-layout-decorate=~{layout/default.html} as well

I made it work with manually adding the thymeleaf dialect dependency:

```
compile('nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect')
```

But I thought that this should be a transitive dependency already present in Spring and I should not have to add it manually...

Answer (score 5):

Thank you Smajl, adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId> nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

solved the issue also for me.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot 2 does not bundle Thymeleaf 2.0 but 3.0. Whilst the overall syntax remained the same there have been many changes under the hood. It seems like you are not having problems with Thymeleaf but the layout plugin since your login pages renders but just the layout is not applied. The layout plugin has been rewritten from scratch in for Thymeleaf 3.0

Layout Dialect 2.0 migration guide: https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/MigrationGuide.html
Thymeleaf 3.0 migration guide: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html

Comment: I noticed that `layout:decorator` was renamed to `layout:decorate` but there must be something else. I will try to dig into the docs...

Comment: I'm wondering if this issue has ever been resolved? I'm experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: For me, the solution was to use:      <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
 xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" lang="en"
 layout:decorate="~{layouts/main}">