# Springboot 2.0.2 not working with thymeleaf template, throwing 404 error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Springboot 1.5.7 for my rest api application, and I am using thymeleaf template to send emails from my api. But when I updated the version of spring boot to 2.0.2 its throwing 404 error i.e "Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers".

Below is the config I have in application.yml

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
    enabled: true
    mode: HTML5
    prefix: /templates/
    suffix: .html
```

thymeleaf version in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the template structure i am using,

[image]

My app release is very near and I am badly stuck with this problem, if someone can provide me workaround then it would be a great help.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? you should accept the answer if it solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `prefix: /templates/` from `application.yml`

If still does not work, add `thymeleaf-layout-dialect` dependency (See: [Thymeleaf stopped resolving layout templates after migrating to Thymeleaf 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231742/thymeleaf-stopped-resolving-layout-templates-after-migrating-to-thymeleaf-3))

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

FYI, I put my views in `WEB-INF/webapp/views`, so I am using `prefix: /WEB-INF/webapp/views/` (spring boot war deploy to tomcat)

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the 2.0 migration guide.

> The Thymeleaf starter included the thymeleaf-layout-dialect dependency
>   previously. Since Thymeleaf 3.0 now offers a [native way to implement
>   layouts](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#template-layout),
>   we removed that mandatory dependency and leave this choice up to you.
>   If your application is relying on the layout-dialect project, please
>   add it explicitly as a dependency.

Adding the following dependencies should work

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

SOURCE : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#template-engines

Comment: Not adding dependency of `layout-dialect` will cause a problem to resolve layout template, not 404. And how is your answer different than the first one (`thymeleaf-layout-dialect` dependency also mentioned there)